# How Can I Declare A Global Variables Model In BLAZOR?

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

How Can I Declare A Global Variables Model In BLAZOR WASM?
Let's say I have the following model and I want to be able to access every variable from the model anywhere in my entire project (pages, services, components, anywhere).
Can you help me, please ?

```
public class UserInfoGlobalClass
{
    public string User_Name { get; set; } = "JOHN SMITH";
    public string User_Email { get; set; } = "JOHNSMITH@gmail.com";
    public string User_Role { get; set; } = "Administrator";
    public string USER_ID { get; set; } = "85f04683-0d37-4947-a09d-bbb464a92480";

}
```

Comment: Inject the model as a service.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can inject your class as a singleton service:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserInfoGlobalClass>();
```

In a service include the class as a `ctor` paramater.

In a component or page:
`@inject UserInfoGlobalClass UserInfoGlobalClass`

For this to be dynamic though. You will need to embellish your class with an event to notify pages and components to call `StateHasChanged()` when the contents are updated. I normally set the properties to private set and expose a method to change them that finally invokes the event to notify listeners.

```
public class UserInfoGlobalClass
{
    public string User_Name { get; private set; } = "JOHN SMITH";
    public string User_Email { get; set; } = "JOHNSMITH@gmail.com";
    public string User_Role { get; set; } = "Administrator";
    public string USER_ID { get; set; } = "85f04683-0d37-4947-a09d-bbb464a92480";
    
    public event EventHandler UserChangedEvent;

    public void SetUser(User user)
    {
        User_Name = user.Name;
        ... repeat for properties.
        UserChangedEvent?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Use in another service.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<SomeOtherService>();
```

```
public class SomeOtherService : IDisposable
{

    private readonly UserInfoGlobalClass userInfoGlobalClass;

    public SomeOtherService(UserInfoGlobalClass userInfoGlobalClass)
    {
        this.userInfoGlobalClass = userInfoGlobalClass;
        userInfoGlobalClass.UserChangedEvent += UserChanged;
    }

    public void UserChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Process user details change.
    }

    public void SetNewUserMethod()
    {
         userInfoGlobalClass.SetUser(new User { ... });
    }

    
    public void Dispose() => userInfoGlobalClass.UserChangedEvent -= UserChanged;
}
```

In a page or component:

```
@implements IDisposable
@inject UserInfoGlobalClass UserInfoGlobalClass

...

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        userInfoGlobalClass.UserChangedEvent += StateHasChanged;  
    }
    
    public void public void Dispose() => userInfoGlobalClass.UserChangedEvent -= StateHasChanged;
}
```

Comment: I actually did that based on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5Y8s1hgEOU .

But I can't use the global variables model from another service because I get the an error.
Please tell me how can I use UserInfoGlobalClass inside another service because I want to use one or more variables from another service.
@inject UserInfoGlobalClass UserInfoGlobalClass in another service is not working.

Can you provide more detailed info for :
"You will need to embellish your class with an event to notify pages and components to call StateHasChanged() when the contents are updated." ?
Thanks

Comment: @TomCat I padded out my answer hope that helps.

Comment: The bottom line is :
I want to be able to access all the global variables from the public class UserInfoGlobalClass on the entire project !

All the global variables from the public class UserInfoGlobalClass are initialized to desired values only when a user logs in and out. 

Can you provide me the simplest way about doing what I want ?

Thank You Very Much !

Comment: I think this answer is still missing some crucial information: who calls SetUser(); in your statement "In a service include the class as a ctor paramater" - what does this code look like?

Comment: Also, I get the error CS0123: No overload for 'StateHasChanged' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Answer (score 17):

How about using a CascadingParameter?  Quick example:

### To make your variables available across all components:

In MainLayout.razor - in the @code section:

```
 private UserInfoGlobalClass userInfo = new UserInfoGlobalClass();
```

In MainLayout.razor - Around the @Body section:

```
  <CascadingValue Value="@userInfo">
      @Body
  </CascadingValue>
```

Then, in any of your components where you need to access the UserInfoGlobalClass object - in the @code section:

```
  [CascadingParameter]
  public UserInfoGlobalClass? userInfo { get; set; }
```

### To use these variables in a service:

In my case, I would simply pass the object or required variable as a parameter to the services where I need to use it:

MyComponent.razor:

```
{
    await MyService.Get(userInfo);
}
```

MyService.cs:

```
public List<MyObject> Get(UserInfoGlobalClass userInfo)
{
   //...service logic here
}
```

In my own project, I use this, for example, when I need to pass the CurrentUser (ApplicationUser) to several components across my entire project, and want to load the current user only once. You can read more about using cascading parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cascadingparameter-attribute).

However, using Cascading Parameters [could have drawback and trade-offs](https://chrissainty.com/understanding-cascading-values-and-cascading-parameters/).  What I like about Cascading Parameters, is that if a cascading value is changed then the new value will be sent down the component tree and all components that use it will be updated. But this can have performance issues if the values constantly change.

Comment: Up voted as this is a good solution for handling current user info which is not changing very often. It also seems to have some advantages: [Microsoft - Blazor cascading values and parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-6.0)